# tracing javascript error on iPhone webapp

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications

I'm getting a NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR error using a jquery library on an iPhone & iPod (but not the iPad Emulator, Chrome, Firefox or Safari).  As I understand it, this error is caused by either manipulating the DOM when its not ready or adding invalid XHTML if strict checking is in force (which it seems to be on iPhone from what I gleaned from other searches).

So, my question is - is it possible to get the JS stacktrace on iPhone so I can identify what bit of my code is causing this problem? I have Xcode and the iPhone SDK on a Mac, but I don't have much experience - so if someone could point to some way to use this it would be great.

Thanks, Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

for useful debugging on an iOS device, try this: http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/ 
it may not give you a good stack trace but it will at least let you inspect the app better.
some code explaining what's going on might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tracing software but maybe - probably stating the obvious - insert some console.error("Error: ") or console.log("Info..") lines in your code?

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid having to get into that as the problem appears to be deep in A library I'm not familiar with.